# How do i iterate through json data sent from backend in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

im able to receive json data in react sent as response from the backend. this is my simple reactjs code;

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

class FileUpload extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            selectedFile:'',
            responseData:[],
        }

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            selectedFile: event.target.files[0],
          })
    }

    submit(){
        const data = new FormData()
        data.append('file', this.state.selectedFile)
        console.warn(this.state.selectedFile);
        let url = "http://localhost/myschool/phpApi/kar.php";

        axios.post(url, data, { // receive two parameter endpoint url ,form data
        })
        .then(res => { // then print response status
            console.warn(res);
            let myjsondata = res;
            console.log(myjsondata.data.sent);
            this.setState({responseData: myjsondata.data.sent});

        })


    }

    render(){

        return(
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                        <br /><br />
                        
                            <h3 className="text-white">React File Upload - Nicesnippets.com</h3>
                            <br />
                            <div className="form-row">
                                <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label className="text-white">Select File :</label>
                                    <input type="file" className="form-control" name="upload_file" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="form-row">
                                <div className="col-md-6">
                                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-dark" onClick={()=>this.submit()}>Save</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );

    }
}

export default FileUpload;
```

when i console.log my response data, i see the json response sent is this;

```
{"Peter":"35","Ben":"37","Joe":"43"}
```

now i want to access the value of peter so that when i try to access `this.state.responsedata.Peter` i get 35.

im not an expert in react but just help me

Comment: You seem to have `responseData` initialised as an array but set to an object, this isn't a problem exactly in JS, but initialising to null may help you avoid confusion later.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already ok.
Just a piece of advice, as your key of the json object, is a string, it is better to access data as `this.state.responseData['Peter']`
Also please make sure you use `responseData` and not `responsedata` as it is industry standard to use camelcase variable names.

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

class FileUpload extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            selectedFile:'',
            responseData:[],
        }

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            selectedFile: event.target.files[0],
          })
    }

    submit(){
        const data = new FormData()
        data.append('file', this.state.selectedFile)
        console.warn(this.state.selectedFile);
        let url = "http://localhost/myschool/phpApi/kar.php";

        axios.post(url, data, { // receive two parameter endpoint url ,form data
        })
        .then(res => { // then print response status
            console.warn(res);
            let myjsondata = res;
            console.log(myjsondata.data.sent);
            this.setState({responseData: myjsondata.data.sent});

        })


    }

    render(){

        return(
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                        <br /><br />
                        
                            <h3 className="text-white">React File Upload - Nicesnippets.com</h3>
                            <br />
                            <div className="form-row">
                                <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label className="text-white">Select File :</label>
                                    <input type="file" className="form-control" name="upload_file" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="form-row">
                                <div className="col-md-6">
                                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-dark" onClick={()=>this.submit()}>Save</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );

    }
}

export default FileUpload;
```

Comment: i want to access the value and print it in the render function. how do i do that?